# SQL - where column in another recordset from another database

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, asp-classic, where-in

I am familiar with "IN" clause in sql e.g.

`select * from table1 where myfield in (select myfield from table2)`

I am now between two databases! I want to select recordset where phone is in other recordset from another database. I am not working directly with sql server. You may suggest me a more complex method using a server side language e.g. php or asp etc.

My test in **classic asp** (where connectionObject1 connects to first database and connectionObject2 connects to second database) :

```
sql="select phone from persons"
recordset1.open sql,connectionObject1

sql="select * from persons where phone in ("& recordset1 &")"
recordset2.open sql,connectionObject2
```

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch

Comment: Are these two databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes they are in same server and a single user has access to both of them. But we have specified different "default database" to those two connection objects.

Comment: You may want to consider using a [cross database query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/cross-database-queries), so the databases can be queried together. You will need to check performance depending on how much data you're querying and other issues. but then the results you are looking for would be a simple query from one of the dbs, rather than manipulating 2 separate results.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
sql="select * from persons where phone in ("& recordset1 &")"
```

You are trying to concatenate strings, but `recordset1` is a recordset as the name suggests, not a string.

I just looked this up. You should be able to convert your recordset to string with `GetString` thus:

```
sql = "select * from persons where phone in (" & 
        recordset1.GetString(adClipString, -1, ",", ",") &
      ")"
```

If phones are not numeric, you'd need additional quotes:

```
sql = "select * from persons where phone in (" & 
        "'" &
        recordset1.GetString(adClipString, -1, "','", "','") &
        "'" &
      ")"
```

I may be mistaken with the syntax. In that case look up your docs.

Comment: This worked for me however I changed adClipString to 2 and also I put nothing in place of -1. I also had to remove last comma and quote from end of string

Answer (score 1):

Use fully-qualified object names in SQL, this should work:

```
sql="select * from [DB1Name].[SchemaName].persons where phone in (select phone from [DB2Name].[SchemaName].persons)"
```

Comment: That's cute. You can even shorten this to `select * from persons`. The OP, however, is selecting from two different persons tables residing in two different databases.

Comment: You are right, didn't pay close attention... Thanks.